# Gradle settings cannot be cast error

Tags: android, android-studio

org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings error while trying to build new project

I downloaded http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip manually and copied zip contents to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle folder and copied gradle.jar from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle\lib to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\lib but still unable to build my first project in android studio.

Comment: Why did you download it manually? Why not let AndroidStudio install gradle when you first create a project

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading the full zip file from [here](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip). Then manually copy it's contents to `C:\Documents and Settings\(Your name)\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\`

If this does work, try to re-install Android Studio and follow these steps again.

If your running Windows 7 64-bit, try to edit `android-studio\bin\studio.bat`

```
SET VM_OPTIONS_FILE=%IDE_BIN_DIR%\studio%BITS%.exe.vmoptions 

to 

**SET VM_OPTIONS_FILE=%IDE_BIN_DIR%\studio%BITS%.exe**

SET JRE=%JDK%
IF EXIST "%JRE%\jre" SET JRE=%JDK%\jre
SET BITS=
**IF EXIST "%JRE%\lib\amd64" SET BITS=64**
```