# Whenever I create a new project in android studio, I get an error

Tags: android, android-studio

i installed android studio and when i click new project i get error like

[image]

```
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings
```

Comment: if anyone knws how to solve this problem comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio error installing Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "You should download the full zip package from
>   http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip manually
>   and copy this zip package to C:\Documents and Settings(Your
>   name).gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\
>
> If it does works ,you had to re-install Android Studio and take this
>   again.
>
> If you use win7 64bit,Try to edit android-studio\bin\studio.bat
>
> SET VM_OPTIONS_FILE=%IDE_BIN_DIR%\studio%BITS%.exe.vmoptions
>
> to
>
> **SET VM_OPTIONS_FILE=%IDE_BIN_DIR%\studio%BITS%.exe**
>
> SET JRE=%JDK% IF EXIST "%JRE%\jre" SET JRE=%JDK%\jre SET BITS=
>   **IF EXIST "%JRE%\lib\amd64" SET BITS=64**"

Stole from [Gradle settings cannot be cast error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603053/gradle-settings-cannot-be-cast-error)