# Error in Android studio + windows 8 x64 org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have an error when Android Studio began compile project

```
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings
```

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603053/gradle-settings-cannot-be-cast-error) are dosen't work.
Help)